# UserName = Environ$("UserName") not working in latest versions of Windows?

Tags: excel, vba

This code does not appear to work in Windows 7/8?

```
Public Function UserName()
    UserName = Environ$("UserName")
End Function
```

Is there a hack for this?

Regards,

Comment: What version of MSOffice are you using?

Comment: Environ("USERNAME") has worked for more then 10 years on our Windows 2003 SP2 server. After an update of Windows today, it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use:

```
Username = CreateObject("WScript.Network").Username
```

Comment: Works with XP and Win7, sorry I don't know about any others.

Comment: It's 2021 and this solution is still helpful. Worked for me today - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Windows7 using Excel 2010.

```
Environ("username")
```

[image: UserName]
[image: UserName2]