# Excel 2013 - Insert "last modified by user" in field

Tags: vba, excel, insert

I have an inventory checklist that I'm supposed to be maintaining, but we have multiple people in the office that edit and make changes to the document. As a tracking measure, we want to implement a macro that inserts the username of the person who last modified or even opened the file (modified would be better).

I have already tried inserting the following Auto_Open macro:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("Inventory List").Range("D31").Value = Environ("username")
End Sub
```

Where "Inventory List" is the primary worksheet and the cell I want it inserted is D31. I got it to work for my name, but when my coworkers open it and change it, it does not insert their name. I have already saved the file as a macro-enabled worksheet, and they have all allowed and trusted the macro content when they open the file.

Anything I'm doing wrong?

---

Source used: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/run-a-macro-HA102748985.aspx#_Toc304793168

Comment: No, we're all on Windows 7/8 PC's.

Comment: [Does this help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089348/username-environusername-not-working-in-latest-versions-of-windows)? `Username = CreateObject("WScript.Network").Username`

Answer (score 0):

Sheets("Inventory List").Range("D31").Value = Environ("username") should always work.

Question is where other users open this Excel file. do they open it on their own computer?

My strong guess is they have elevated macro security on the computer. Check other users Excel file to see macro security level. Note that this feature does not get copied if you modify in on your own computer and then send it to them.